# Is there a way to define restrictions/constraints to fields when defining GraphQL schema for AWS AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When designing schema for AppSync, like
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/
Is it possible to define constraints in addition to types? We can do:

```
type Todo {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    priority: Int
}
```

But can we do something like

```
    id: ID!
    name: String @restrictions (maxLength: 64)
    description: String @restrictions (maxLength: 255)
    priority: Int @restrictions (min:0, max: 4)
}
```

Otherwise, authorized user will be able to send the data of any length, even megabytes of data to be set into 'string' field if it has no length limit, and this data will go directly into DynamoDB unless there is a lambda function for every field.

Comment: Anyone? Please!

Comment: You should be implementing that in the resolver itself or if it has lambda direct resolver, then in Lambda resolver code

Comment: you mean, use VTL for that?

Comment: Yeah in the place where you would put VTL, keep in mind that instead of VTL you can use JS instead.
But you could also validate that in Lambda if it resolves your request